# Code for number of minima below a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

I am having trouble thinking of a code that could do a certain task.

I have 101 lists of numbers (100 distance which range in values from 10 to ~100 and 1 time. All have the same number of elements) that give the distance of an object over time. I need code that can take these 100 lists and find the percentage of them that have 1 minimum, 2 minima, 3 minima etc. below a certain value (in this case 30.)

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Apologies for the lack of clarification. I should have made it clear that I already have the 100 sets of distance data in the form of lists, I don't need to generate them. Here is an image I hope clarifies my situation a bit.

[image]

This displays 10 of the 100 distance sets over the time. As you can see they have various numbers of minima. I am trying to write a code that can give the number of tables that have 1 or 2 or 3 etc. minima below the value of 30, so for the above example it would be something like 5 for 1 minimum, 2 for 2, 1 for 3 and 2 for 4. Also, the code would preferably have to work for an arbitrary number of lists, not just 100. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: Sample data would make your question clearer. Invert the data to turn minimums into maximums, then use [`FindPeaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html).  [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) can then be used to find the number of peaks above the inverted threshold. [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) the counts to get their multiplicity.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you added more information. Is the time vector truly relevant to this problem? What is your criteria for a discrete minimum? Also, please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have included a sample of 10/100 of the data sets in the form of listlineplots.

Comment: I think @m_goldberg wanted a sample of your data, not an image of it. I think `FindPeaks` should work, as Bob Hanlon suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BobHanlon already told you how to do this. I will flesh it out a bit. Here is an example dataset:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = {
    RandomReal[100, 100],
    Table[50.(1+Sin[x])+2x,{x,Subdivide[0, 20,100]}]
};

plot = ListLinePlot[data, GridLines->{{}, {30}}, GridLinesStyle->Red]
```

[image]

Here is a function to find minima below a threshold:

```
findMinima[t_][list_] := ScalingTransform[{1,-1}] @ FindPeaks[-list, 0, 0, -t]
```

Here are the minima of my example dataset:

```
minima = findMinima[30] /@ data
```

> {{{2., 11.142}, {4., 18.7803}, {6., 6.57388}, {8., 23.1155}, {11., 
>      21.1826}, {14., 24.7495}, {20., 20.8051}, {22., 12.8821}, {30., 
>      16.9013}, {33., 1.18355}, {36., 1.1978}, {42., 26.3269}, {45., 
>      5.53108}, {48., 20.3011}, {53., 18.586}, {56., 19.9524}, {59., 
>      27.8197}, {65., 27.355}, {69., 3.81167}, {79., 20.1479}, {82., 
>      22.0603}, {84., 21.5517}, {87., 1.78401}, {90., 8.95166}, {93., 
>      19.6453}, {96., 11.7225}, {100., 3.70128}}, {{24., 9.51545}, {56., 
>      22.0005}}}

and a plot showing that these points are indeed minima:

```
Show[plot, Epilog -> {Red, Point @ Catenate @ %552}]
```

[image]

So, a function that does what you want is:

```
Tally[Length @* findMinima[30] /@ data]
```

> {{27, 1}, {2, 1}}

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give quite a full description, but here's a guess:

```
t = 100; (* number of periods *)
n = 25; (* number of elements in each list *)
lists = RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {t, n}];
cts = Count[x_ /; x < 30] /@ lists;
time = Range[100];
ListPlot[Transpose[{time, 100*cts/n}]]
```

If you really wanted to count just the minima conditional on size for each list, you can change `cts` to

```
cts = MapThread[Count[#1, x_ /; x == #2 && #2 < 30] &, {lists, Min /@ lists}]
```